# Centering Headings in PHP/CSS?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I thought I had figured this out in the Custom CSS box of this Wordpress theme but no joy. I just can’t get the headings centered!

http://growing-underground.com/ (password = nugget13)

I really want to get these headings centered – I managed it using inline styling but when I try to do it in the Custom CSS box it doesn’t work – I must be targetting the wrong object. Also, I really want to get rid of the full-width grey underline and just have a black underline on the heading.

I am starting to see why using these premium Wordpress themes is a pain as they all do things differently...

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific: which headings are you talking about? The gray border lines can be done away with by removing the `border-bottom` and `border-top` lines on line numbers 15 and 16 of `fullslider.css`.

Comment: I am talking about the gray border - sorry. However, your solution will only work for the dotted lines in the homepage slider - those are fine and I want to keep those.

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP

Comment: I think the only thing it has to do with PHP is that I am a n00b and I couldn't find the thing I wanted to change in style.css, so I figured it may be something to do with the PHP. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this below your last declared `CSS` stylesheet at the bottom and you will get your headings to be aligned at the `center`.

```
.page-section div.heading h5, section.page-section .titleBar h2 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Q875p/)**

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is excellent - thank you. Now my only real problem involves the silly grey underlines (and also the black top border on the Contact page h5 bits).

Comment: for that, you need to add this below your last declared CSS stylesheet at the bottom `.page-section .titleBar{background:none;}` - @AndyAshwin

Comment: Thanks ever so much Nathan! Amazing.

Answer (score 0):

```
.page-section .titleBar {
    text-align: center;
}

section.page-section .titleBar h2 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 0 0 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathon. However, I actually only want the border to be the width of the text, like an underline - this goes to the full width of the container.